# How to create a singleton pattern which changes its single object by overriding when parameters are changed

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

How to create a single object which changes when its parameters are changed. I mean, it occurs by crushing the other object. it contains still one object but its object is changed if parameters are changed.

```
public static singletonPattern getObject(int param1, int param2) {
        return obj = (obj == null) ? new singletonPattern(param1,param2) : obj;
  }
```

Here, In case of parameters are changed. It needs to produce a new object and replace previous one with the new one and send it as its object.

Comment: crushing the other object?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you give a more detailed example? Perhaps some code demonstrating the behaviour you're trying to avoid by doing this?

Comment: If it changes its object then it isn't a Singleton.

Comment: Do you mean getting the instance with new parameters? If yes, handle that in your `getInstance(param1, param2)` method… create a new object on param change.

Comment: Have a normal singleton with a method that updates its state according to the new parameters.

Comment: Singleton means the keeping only one object and to prevent from producing new ones. However, sometimes it needs to change this single object one time. For example first time, you connect to a default database. after you changed parameters you need new one.this object is my new object to connect database. This object will not change anymore. This is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I mean that.

```
public static singletonPattern getInstance(int param1, int param2) {
    return obj = (obj == null) ? new singletonPattern(int param1, int param2) : 
            obj == new singletonPattern(int param1, int param2) ? obj : new singletonPattern(context);
}
```